# Converting code to QGIS tool

Tags: qgis, gdal

**Code**

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal

def merge_tiff_files(input_folder, output_path):
    tif_files = [f for f in os.listdir(input_folder) if f.endswith(".tif")]

    if not tif_files:
        print("No TIFF files found in the input folder.")
        return

    gdal.AllRegister()

    input_dataset = gdal.Open(os.path.join(input_folder, tif_files[0]), gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    driver = input_dataset.GetDriver()

    output_dataset = driver.Create(output_path, input_dataset.RasterXSize, input_dataset.RasterYSize, 1, input_dataset.GetRasterBand(1).DataType)

    for tif_file in tif_files:
        input_dataset = gdal.Open(os.path.join(input_folder, tif_file), gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
        output_dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(input_dataset.ReadAsArray())

    output_dataset.FlushCache()
    output_dataset = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_folder = r"E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2"
    output_path = r"E:\Spekter\Task 2\OutputFile.tif"

    merge_tiff_files(input_folder, output_path)
    print("Merged TIFF file saved to", output_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use QGIS' Python API for that.

The QGIS Python API is documented at https://qgis.org/pyqgis/latest/

The cookbook provides an introduction and many common examples at https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/